# How i can use Bootstrap Popover inside a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

How i can use bootstrap popover inside a submit button?

I tried this:

HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" rel="popover"  data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-original-title="Popover test" value="{$progress}%)" class="button_submit">
```

JS code:

```
<script>
 $("a[rel=popover]").popover();
 </script>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What is not happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong selector...

```
<script>
 $("input[rel=popover]").popover();
 </script>
```